# PHP never receives nested jQuery $.post data

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm trying to send simple form data from my index page to a PHP function, checklogin.php. What I'm finding is that no data, serialized or even direct input, is getting through to the PHP function. I know for a fact that the jQuery function is getting called, and I also know that the PHP file is called because I've put various post functions in.

When I submit data directly from the form using `action="checklogin.php"` the $_POST data is correctly received and I can process it. However when using jQuery to intercept the form submit, no data is received.

One thing to note is that the actual login form HTML is inserted from another page, to allow me to work on multiple pages instead of one big index file.

**Form - login.php**

```
<form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="post">
    <td>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="78">Username</td>
                <td width="6">:</td>
                <td width="294"><input name="username" type="text" id="username"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><input name="password" type="text" id="password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
   </td>
</form>
```

**Submit event hook - Index.php**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {                
    $.post("login.php", function(data) { // retrieve login form from other page.
        $("#page5").html(data); 
        $('#loginform').submit(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            var formData = $(this).serialize();

            console.log("Form Data: " + formData); // this is not blank

            $.post("checklogin.php", formData, function(data) {
                // post-login actions
            })

            });
        });
    })
});
```

**checklogin.php** (temporary until is problem resolved)

```
<?php
    print_r($_POST);
?>
```

As I said, even direct input such as "username=test$password=blah" instead of 'formData' results in an empty $_POST array. I've also tried using the ajax equivalent post call with no luck.

**JavaScript Console Output**

```
// console.log line above $.post
Form Data: username=test&password=blah

// Result from PHP print_r
Array
(
)
```

Comment: also: $('#loginform').submit(function () { event.preventDefault(); this should be: $('#loginform').submit(function (event) { event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).on('submit','#loginform',function () { //code here }
```

or better use

```
$('#page5').on('submit','#loginform',function () { //code here }
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

Comment: @Boaz see his jQuery he is loading form on client side .

Comment: You're right, but by the time the `submit` handler is bound the form definitely exists. OP is also saying the handler is executed.

Comment: The handler does get executed so that's not the issue here. Although this does allow me to move the code outside the nested first $.post function so it's appreciated.

Comment: try `<?php echo '<pre>',print_r($_POST,true),'</pre>' ?>`and `$.post("checklogin.php", formData, function(data) {
               console.log(data)
            })`

Comment: I think you're onto something there, it's correctly receiving the data now, although I'm not entirely sure how the code difference from the original causes this change.

Comment: @JohanRensenbrink now you are getting data from server .What you want ?

Comment: Well, it's definitely getting the data through so I'm gonna say that answers that. Thanks!